# define custom configuration in sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

I want to set another set of options for running tests in integration server and in dev environment.

Let's have this option:

```
testOptions := Seq(Tests.Filter(s => Seq("Spec", "Unit").exists(s.endsWith(_))))
```

How can change the `testOptions`, so it is only applied, when the `test` command is prefixed with some scope like `teamcity:test`?

I expect, that the testOptions would be modified with similar syntax:

```
testOptions in Teamcity := ...
```

I also would like to know, how to define the custom scope, preferable in simple `*.sbt` build, not in `project/*.scala` build.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The scope could be either project, configuration, or task. In this case, I think you're looking to define a custom configuration.

### using itSettings

There's a built-in configuration called `IntegrationTest` already. You can define it in your build definition by writing:

```
Defaults.itSettings
```

This will use completely different setup from normal tests including the test code (goes into `src/it/scala/`) and libraries, so this may not be what you want.

### defining your own configuration

Using sbt 0.13, you can define a custom configuration as follows in build.sbt:

```
val TeamCity = config("teamcity") extend(Test)

val root = project.in(file(".")).
  configs(TeamCity).
  settings(/* your stuff here */, ...)
```

### defining teamcity:test

Now you have to figure out how to define `teamcity:test`.

**Edit**: Mark Harrah pointed out to me that there's a documentation for this. See [Additional test configurations with shared sources](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.0/docs/Detailed-Topics/Testing.html#additional-test-configurations-with-shared-sources).

> An alternative to adding separate sets of test sources (and compilations) is to share sources. In this approach, the sources are compiled together using the same classpath and are packaged together.

### putting it all together

```
val TeamCity = config("teamcity") extend(Test)

val root = project.in(file(".")).
  configs(TeamCity).
  settings( 
    name := "helloworld",
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "org.specs2" %% "specs2" % "2.2" % "test"
    )
  ).
  settings(inConfig(TeamCity)(Defaults.testTasks ++ Seq(
    testOptions := Seq(Tests.Argument("nocolor"))
  )): _*)
```

When you run `teamcity:test` the Specs2 output displays without color.

Comment: I do as you say, but adding `testOptions in AsyncTest := Seq(Tests.Filter(s => s.contains("Async")))` to the `inConfig` settings still runs the entire test suite `async:test` ... Also if I add `postLinkJSEnv in AsyncTest := new PhantomJSEnv(autoExit = false)` then it runs with default PhantomJSEnv... What is exactly the second parameter of the `inConfig` method?

Comment: @lisak seems like this is a bug: https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/2340