# Macro project - macro in its own configuration

Tags: scala, macros, sbt, scala-macros

The SBT documentation about [Macro Projects](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Detailed-Topics/Macro-Projects.html) starts with the following:

> The current macro implementation in the compiler requires that macro implementations be compiled before they are used. The solution is typically to put the macros in a subproject or in their own configuration.

What does exactly mean to put the macros "in their own configuration"? Does it mean there is an alternative to putting macro source in a subproject? If so, what would that alternative be? I'm looking for an option where I'd not have to separate macro source from invocations, mainly because I don't want yet another subproject for common code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the author refers to the [Configuration scop](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Getting-Started/Scopes.html#scoping-by-configuration-axis). In short: you already know that diffrent sources can reside under `src/main/scala` and `src/test/scala`, and that code in the *test configuration* can use code from the *compile (main) configuration*. so why not having a custom configuration, e.g. *macro*, and sources for it can reside under `src/macro/scala`?

there's a [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18789477/define-custom-configuration-in-sbt/18796745#18796745) on this matter, I suggest you take a look.
also, you could find useful examples [here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.0/docs/Detailed-Topics/Testing.html#additional-test-configurations). it's an explanation on defining new configurations for tests. but you could exploit it for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the author meant by *own configuration*.

An alternative is to use SBT's ability to generate sources (*c.f.* sourceGenerators) before they get compiled. "Generating" in fact allows you *for instance* to copy macro source files from elsewhere.

However that's convoluted, so I'd recommend to separate macros in a sub-project. Besides, separating macros still allows you to build even if you switch to an IDE that doesn't support SBT (then you have a macro-defining project and a macro-using project).