# SBT configuration vs Ivy module configuration

Tags: configuration, dependencies, sbt, ivy

This appears similar to [sbt Configuration vs Ivy configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25269375/sbt-configuration-vs-ivy-configuration), though it doesn't seem like this question is asked:

What is the difference between

```
libraryDependencies += "com.example" % "foo" % "1.0" % "test"
```

and

```
libraryDependencies in Test += "com.example" % "foo" % "1.0"
```

(And a similar question for `IntegrationTest` / `"it"`.)

Should I always use SBT configuration, or Ivy configuration? Or does it depend on the particular case?

I have seen the former more often, though it seems that the latter is more consistent with the rest of my build.sbt.

Answer (score 1):

`update` task and `libraryDependencies` are a bit odd ones because when you're downloading JARs you probably don't want to download `Compile` JARs and `Test` JARs independently or in parallel. For `update` task to handle all configurations, `libraryDependencies` needs to handle all configurations too.

```
libraryDependencies += "com.example" % "foo" % "1.0" % Test
```

means your project's `Test` configuration depends on the default configuration of `"com.example" % "foo" % "1.0"`.

`libraryDependencies in Test`, I don't think would work.

> Should I always use SBT configuration, or Ivy configuration? Or does it depend on the particular case?

There are notational differences, but conceptually sbt's configuration and Ivy configuration is the same thing.