# Explaining the Difference between Expressions defining libraryDependencies

Tags: sbt

I'm unable to understand the difference between the following expressions. The expressions a reduced -- the real world case has more settings distributed in seperate objects.

1. specified directly as sequence

   ```
   Seq(libraryDependencies +=
     "org.openjdk.jmh" % "jmh-core" % "1.6.2" % "compile")
   ```
2. wrapped in `inConfig`

   ```
   inConfig(Compile)(libraryDependencies +=
     "org.openjdk.jmh" % "jmh-core" % "1.6.2" % "compile")
   ```

In both cases `show compile:libraryDependencies` shows the same

```
[info] List(org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.10.4, org.openjdk.jmh:jmh-core:1.6.2:compile)
```

but for `show compile:managedClasspath` the dependency towards JMH is only shown in the first case. As a result the normal compiler run fails due to unresolvable classes.

Please explain or point the logical difference between both cases.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SBT configuration vs Ivy module configuration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550889/sbt-configuration-vs-ivy-module-configuration)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR:** Use `% "compile"` **not** `Compile` when declaring `libraryDependencies`

---

What you're seeing is a gap, possibly a bug, in how `sbt` tries to use Ivy's module configurations (such as `compile`) as one of its setting scopes.

For reference:

- [Official docs about Scopes](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Scopes.html)
- [Blog post about sbt "dimensions"](http://eed3si9n.com/4th-dimension-with-sbt-013)

---

The problem lies that, currently, you can declare the configuration at both the value level:

```
  "org.openjdk.jmh" % "jmh-core" % "1.6.2" % "compile"
```

and the key level:

```
  inConfig(Compile)(libraryDependencies += xyz)
```

or alternatively:

```
  libraryDependencies in Compile += xyz
```

As you say in both examples `show compile:libraryDependencies` shows the same sequence, but `show libraryDependencies` demonstrates that you only added `jmh-core` in the `Compile` axes of `libraryDependencies`:

1. `show libraryDependencies`

   ```
   [info] List(org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.10.4, org.openjdk.jmh:jmh-core:1.6.2:compile)
   ```
2. `show libraryDependencies`

   ```
   [info] List(org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.10.4)
   ```

This then leads as to why `show compile:managedClasspath` is different.

Have a look at what `inspect actual compile:managedClasspath` outputs:

```
[info] Task: scala.collection.Seq[sbt.Attributed[java.io.File]]
[info] Description:
[info]  The classpath consisting of external, managed library dependencies.
[info] Provided by:
[info]  {file:/Users/dnw/Desktop/t-2015-04-08.0540/}t-2015-04-08-0540/compile:managedClasspath
[info] Defined at:
[info]  (sbt.Classpaths) Defaults.scala:991
[info] Dependencies:
[info]  *:update
[info]  */*:classpathTypes
[info]  compile:classpathConfiguration
[info]  compile:managedClasspath::streams
[info] Reverse dependencies:
[info]  compile:externalDependencyClasspath
[info] Delegates:
[info]  compile:managedClasspath
[info]  *:managedClasspath
[info]  {.}/compile:managedClasspath
[info]  {.}/*:managedClasspath
[info]  */compile:managedClasspath
[info]  */*:managedClasspath
[info] Related:
[info]  test:managedClasspath
[info]  runtime:managedClasspath
```

The thing to note is its dependency on `*:update`, which isn't scoped to `compile`. From there it eventually leads to `*:libraryDependencies` which in your second example doesn't include `jmh-core`.

Comment: Thanks for your explainations. I think I have to work hard to wrap my mind around the fact `*` not being some globbing operator.