# How to show all config scope axis?

Tags: sbt

From the document of sbt, I see there are 3 scope axis in sbt:

1. project
2. config
3. task

For `project` and `task`, I can use command:

```
projects
tasks
```

to see the list of them of the project.

But how to see the configs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It'd be `ivyConfigurations`.

```
> help ivyConfigurations
The defined configurations for dependency management. This may be different
from the configurations for Project settings.

> ivyConfigurations
[info] List(compile, runtime, test, provided, optional, compile-internal,
runtime-internal, test-internal, plugin, sources, docs, pom, scala-tool)
```

Comment: Thank, Jacek! A question: I defined some config like `val myconf = config("myconf")` in `build.sbt`, it doesn't show on the result of `ivyConfigurations`, is it correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. You need to add the new config to the project with `Project.configs` (see http://stackoverflow.com/q/18789477/1305344) or redefining `ivyConfigurations` (see [Advanced configurations example](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Advanced-Configurations-Example.html)).

Comment: `ivyConfigurations` not working for me. I had to type `ivy-configurations`

Comment: What's your version of sbt? I bet one that begs for upgrade, i.e. pre-0.13.5.